# Date/Time Dimension in Cube

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, olap-cube, cube-dimension

I have a Date Dimension called Dim_Date in my Data Warehouse. Now the issue is that my Date Dimension is only populated till 31st Dec 2011. My cube is built in SSAS. Is there any way I can populate my Date Dim for another 5 years? When I try to Process my Date Dimension from SSAS it does not populate any values. SO what is the best way to insert 5 years value into my date dimension?

Please Help

Cheers
Rushir

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is, presumably you can use the same script that you used to populate the existing data, but just change the end date? A search on this site for "populating calendar table" or similar should give you a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ETL tool (e.g. MS SSIS) for generating data for date dimension table. There is multiple [examples for this](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/), google is your friend.

Comment: THank you guys for your answer.I some how managed to get a Procedure to Populate the Date Table.